# Encoding mismatch on the database and Linux server

Tags: java, linux, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a database which uses the encoding ISO8859_1. I have a spring MVC application that takes the data from the server and displays it on a web page. However my Linux server has the default encoding UTF-8. I am using JDBC connection to get the data from the database. The problem is that data from the database gets corrupted with garbage values when it reaches the server as there is an encoding mismatch. When I try to convert the encoding of the string from the result set to UTF-8 I end up with a string that contains "?". It is trying to encode the garbage string to UTF-8 and that's why I end up with question mark string. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now. If someone has encountered this type of situation then I will be glad to here your answer. (PS: I cannot change the encoding of the database or the server)

Comment: How is the JDBC connection configured? What DBMS do you use?

Comment: I am using a NoSQL database called Universe. I have the application deployed on an application server. So the application server makes use of connection pooling to pool the connection. I just make use of those connections from the pool.

Comment: So how ist the encoding defined in the connection pooling of the application server?

Comment: It takes the default encoding of the server. In this case the default is UTF8